# Google Spreadsheet: How to name a range using Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am using the following code to name a range:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var rangeToName = sheet.getRange(column, column - 1, 1,values.length + rowOffset);
var rangeName = 'F' + '2';

ss.setNamedRange(rangeName, rangeToName); // SCRIPT CRASHES HERE
```

When executing this script, it fails with the error message: `The name you specified for this range is not a valid name.`

I get this error whenever I use a concatenated string (it does not matter if I use to delimit the string with `'` or `"`).

How can I create the name of a range by concatenating two strings or a string and number?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated:

> The specified range name is ambiguous with a cell reference.

For more information, see [Named and protected ranges](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/63175).

Answer (score 1):

I have found the error:

The name for the range may not look like a reference to a cell, e.g. "F2" is an invalid name as it could be a cell. A name may not contain a "-" character.

Comment: "A name may not contain a "-" character."--helped